# Amazon batch - input file from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm new to AWS. I'm trying to use batch to analyze a bunch of files. If I have a docker image that installs my analysis program, what is the recommended way to use I/O with a batch job?

1. Is there a way to access S3 files with generic programs?

   `/bin/cd-hit -i <s3bucket/input> -o <s3bucket/output.txt>`
2. Or do people use amazon elastic file system, mount as volume in job definition, then access files that way?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is there a way to access S3 files with generic programs?

Yes there is.

- http://s3tools.org/s3cmd
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html

> 2. Or do people use amazon elastic file system, mount as volume in job definition, then access files that way?

That also possible even though it is much better to think about S3 as a key value store and write multi-threaded code that accesses S3 in that fashion.

Comment: Also, EFS is much more expensive.

Comment: Yes, but using s3cmd, the file still has to be stored somewhere for input into a program. So you have to copy it somewhere. Do people just use a generic volume, copy the input file there, then write the output to s3 with s3cmd?

Comment: @jwillis0720 yes usually copy it to a local temporary location